# jquery can't find text

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE:**

So I added a function that displays the length but the user current has to click something to fire it:

```
function check() {
    alert($("#currentTechnicalPositions").html().length);
}
```

And this works...  So I'm thinking that it has to be outside of the $(document).ready section:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.topnav').mobileMenu({
        combine: false,
        switchWidth: 600,
        indentString: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',
        prependTo: 'nav#topnav'
    });

    $('#currentTechnicalPositions').rssfeed('http://xyz.com', {
        limit: 100,
        content: false,
        header: false,
        media: false,
        linktarget: '_blank'
    });
});
```

Is there an onComplete event that I can attach?  If nothing returns from the rssfeed I want to display a message to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.length` only returns the number of matched elements. I think you want to check it with something like `.html()` or `.children().length`.

Answer (score 1):

To check if there is any content in the div, whether it be unformatted text or html elements, you can do

```
$("currentTechnicalPositions").html().length
```

which will return the number of characters within the div, including html tags.

Comment: there is an onchange method you can run, if that will help you. or you can use the setTimeout(fxn, timeMilli) function to run your updater after x milliseconds... less clean, but would work.